# Make element transparent for clicks with css

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have this code and unfortunatlyI can't touch the html to make the figcaption a child of the `<a>`. The thing is that the figcaption is absolutly positioned over the `<a>` so that area is not clickable. I'd like to make it clicable with css, is it possible?

Right now, the  tag is under the figcaption, so the figcaption prevents the click from happening.

```
<figure class="gallery-item">
  <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
    <a href="" style="
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
">
      <img width="200" height="162" src="http://static.hogarmania.com/archivos/201204/estrenimiento-gato-bebe2-xl-668x400x80xX.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <figcaption class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption" id="gallery-1-123">
    Pintura al óleo de un planeta toroidal
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: You expect that result, click <figcaption> and opacity image?

Comment: `Pointer-events:none` but it is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @Paulie_D do you refer to this http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20pointer ? It is  not supported by ie8-10 but in general it seems quite good. Thanks?